# Xamarin Native to Forms transition

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation

I am working with the Xamarin forms app that uses native camera. I am trying to switch from Forms to Native and then back to forms based on https://github.com/supreettare/Forms2Native2Forms/blob/master/FormsBasics.Android/FormsActivity.cs

in Android:
SetPage (App.GetSecondPage ());

in Forms:

```
public static Page GetSecondPage ()
    {
        var formsPage = new NavigationPage (new MyThirdPage ()); 

        return formsPage;
    }
```

My concern is when I call this function it gives me **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class**.

If I do SetPage(new GetSecondPage()), I can navigate to the other page but then **can not use Navigation.PushAsync()** anywhere on that page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Navigate between Android Specific Pages and Shared Pages in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791878/how-to-navigate-between-android-specific-pages-and-shared-pages-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing as a I mentioned above, but doing that I get the error above. I am passing the imagebyte as the parameter in the page constructor. It looks like SetPage(App.RetryPage(imageBytes));

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `Page.CreateSupportFragment` method ?

In your activity,you could load the page which defined in your forms like

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);          
    Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment mainPage = YourPage.CreateSupportFragment(this);
    SupportFragmentManager
        .BeginTransaction()
        .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, mainPage)
        .Commit();

}
```

you could refer to [Nativie Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms#android)

Comment: This is basically using forms inside the native platform, if I am not wrong?

Comment: Actually, that would be a lot of work for me. I also want to implement iOS and i will have to do the same. Therefore, i was trying to minimise the native functionalities while keeping just Camera native. If nothing helps, I will have to do it.

Comment: you also could use similar method `Page.CreateViewController` in ios. and another way you may use messagingcenter to communicate between native and forms,then switch froms each other

Comment: Used messagingcenter as you advised :  

Code in App.cs
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "GoBack", (s) => {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage()));
            });

Code in another page that sends: 
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "GoBack")

Error:
 Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x8e (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{669a3c6 #2 id=0x8e}'