# How can I navigate to android layout from Xamarin.froms

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I developed an app using Xamarin.forms. So I've three main folders and files as below:

**MyProject_xamarin:**

MainPage.xaml

Page1.xaml

Page2.xaml

...

**MyProject_xamarin.Android**

...

Resource>>Layout>>activity_main.xml
activity_main.xml has the following code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/SubscribeToRegion1"
        android:text="Region 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/SubscribeToRegion2"
        android:text="R2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!--  ... and three more switch controls -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

the C# code that I have to handle this was written in MainActivity.cs as below:

```
            using System;

    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Util;
    using Firebase.Iid;
    using Android.Gms.Common;
    using Firebase.Messaging;

    namespace Notifications.Droid
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Notifications", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
        public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
        {
            TextView msgText;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
                ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //     var btnGetData = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
                msgText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.msgText);
                // var Unscbscribe = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.UnscbscribefromAll);

                var btnRegion1 = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SubscribeToRegion1);
                var btnRegion2 = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SubscribeToRegion2);
                var btnRegion3 = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SubscribeToRegion3);
                var btnRegion4 = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SubscribeToRegion4);
                var btnRegion5 = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SubscribeToRegion5);

                // default values (all checked), we need some sort of (remember changes)
                btnRegion1.Checked = true;
                btnRegion2.Checked = true;
                btnRegion3.Checked = true;
                btnRegion4.Checked = true;
                btnRegion5.Checked = true;

                btnRegion1.CheckedChange += (a, b) =>
                 {
                     bool isChecked = b.IsChecked;
                     if (isChecked)
                         FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("R1");
                     else
                         FirebaseMessaging.Instance.UnsubscribeFromTopic("R1");
                 };

                btnRegion2.CheckedChange += (c, d) =>
                {
                    bool isChecked = d.IsChecked;
                    if (isChecked)
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("R2");
                    else
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.UnsubscribeFromTopic("R2");
                };

                btnRegion3.CheckedChange += (e, f) =>
                {
                    bool isChecked = f.IsChecked;
                    if (isChecked)
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("R3");
                    else
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.UnsubscribeFromTopic("R3");
                };

                btnRegion4.CheckedChange += (g, h) =>
                {
                    bool isChecked = h.IsChecked;
                    if (isChecked)
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("R4");
                    else
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.UnsubscribeFromTopic("R4");
                };

                btnRegion5.CheckedChange += (i, j) =>
                {
                    bool isChecked = j.IsChecked;
                    if (isChecked)
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("R5");
                    else
                        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.UnsubscribeFromTopic("R5");
                };


            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }




        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

**miemss_xamarin.iOS**

### ...

Now in the mainPage.xaml I've buttons, each one navigate to a specific page as below:

```
   ... <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Source="img`enter code here`.png"  
                       Grid.Row="1"  
                       Grid.Column="0"  
                       BackgroundColor="White" 
                       WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" 
                     >
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_2"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                    <Label Text="CBRNE Resources" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackLayout> ...
```

and I used the code below to navigate to the new page:

```
                private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
            }



....
```

What I did, made the project start from Page1.xaml.  But I don't know what I need to change in order to open this xml file only I click on the button above (instead of Page2).. Hope it make sense now,

Comment: You can navigate between pages. There is no way how to navigate to a xml file. Have a look at Xamarin's navigation [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

Comment: The Xamarin.android includes the Firebase.Messaging library which I can’t add in Xamarin.forms. I want The user to make  Selections (subscriptions in topics) which are listed in the XML layout which has switches for topics (e.g. Promotions, news,..). is there any way that I can handle this?@MouseOnMars

Comment: Could you give a sample of how the xml looks like? That way my answer will be more specific and helpful. At least I hope so

Comment: I've updated my original post @MouseOnMars and added more info. The Current situation here actually is that we are a group. First group work on Xamarin.Forms and created the xaml pages, and worked on the Xamarin.andriod (created the xml file and the code behind in the MainActivity.cs. and the problem happened when we wanted to merge these two different projects! Any help that you can afford would be really appreciated.

Comment: I tried to just simply create xaml file and add my switch controls. but the problem as I mentioned is the when I try to add "using Firebase.Messaging" library that I could not include in Xamarin.Forms @MouseOnMars

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791878/how-to-navigate-between-android-specific-pages-and-shared-pages-in-xamarin-forms